# How can I set a variable upfront and pass it to tests?

Tags: casperjs

I have here a setup similar to [the gist referenced in the FAQ](https://gist.github.com/n1k0/3813361). One difference is that I have also my sensitive information in ***inc.coffee***, so to avoid having to spread them everywhere.

```
data =
  BaseURL: "http://localhost:3000"
  Name: "Foo Bar"
  Login: 
    email :    'foo'
    password : 'bar'
```

This ***data*** variable, however, is not being made available to the test scripts. Any idea on how to pass its information?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS has a module system like the one in Node.js since 1.7.0. So make your configuration a function and export it.

Comment: Would you give an example? What command should I use to export this function in the init file and then import in the test file?